# CSS blur() renders weird lines in DIVs

Tags: html, css, frontend, rendering, blur

I have the problem that in several browsers the use of blur(120px) leads to such ugly lines in the gradient, but I also don't know what it could be.
How can I hide these lines so that it looks like a clean transition?

[image: a site with several blurred divs]

[image]

I've already tried to use `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` and `transform: translateZ(0)` from other stackoverflow posts, what didn't work so far.

```css
.pink-bg-bubble {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--pink);
    height: 15vw;
    width: 15vw;
    filter: blur(140px);
    margin-left: 15%;
    z-index: 200 !important;
}

.purple-bg-bubble {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--purple);
    height: 15vw;
    width: 15vw;
    margin-left: 10%;
    filter: blur(160px);
    margin-top: 30%;
    z-index: 200 !important;
}

.blue-bg-bubble {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
    margin-left: 42%;
    filter: blur(200px);
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 12%;
    z-index: 200 !important;
}

.yellow-bg-bubble {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--yellow);
    height: 15vw;
    width: 15vw;
    margin-left: 71%;
    filter: blur(170px);
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 30%;
    z-index: 200 !important;
}

.green-bg-bubble {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--green);
    height: 12vw;
    width: 12vw;
    margin-left: 77%;
    filter: blur(130px);
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    z-index: 200 !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code used so that others might observe this effect

Comment: Sorry, is added now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is inevitable. The blur is affecting the element every 120px in a circle shape. However, you can try using backdrop-filter: blur(60px); along with filter: blur(120px); I'm not really sure about it working, but you must try.

Comment: Thank you!
This unfortunately didn't work on my end. :/